# Is there a way to turn off the controller schematic?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In the bottom corners of the screen there is a picture of the Wiimote with labels that tell you what each of the buttons currently do. It is incredibly distracting, and I feel comfortable enough with the controls that I don't really need it anymore.

How do I make it go away?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Note: This is not available until you insert the first tablet (confirmed by @kareen and @jeffmercado)

Open up the gear menu with "1", and you'll see an interface button near the bottom left area of the screen. It should have "Standard" on it. Set it to "Pro" to remove the button layout.

Here is a picture of the button:

[image]

(original image taken from: http://www.zeldadungeon.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/ss-gear1.jpg)

Here is the location of it (circled):

[image]

(original image taken from: http://www.zeldadungeon.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/ss-gear.png )

Comment: Note, it's not available to you at the start, only until after a certain point in the game.  (right after you put in the first tablet I believe)

Comment: @JeffMercado I thought it was the second tablet.

Comment: @Powerlord: I'm pretty sure it was before that. I know I was able to set it to `Pro` before I went into the forest. It might have been when you get the `Sailcloth`.  Because I distinctly remember being able to set it once you left the `Goddess Statue`.

Comment: @Powerlord It's not the second. I did it before leaving Skyloft.

Comment: It's available after you put in the first tablet. Fi will pop out and tell you about it before you set off for your adventure.

Comment: To be precise, `Fi` will tell you about it after you get your green clothes and you try to leave the academy grounds.